# Extract data from WebPage via chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, keyword

I am looking to make a chrome extension which is continuously scans the webpage I'm currently on, and looks for certain keywords that I type, and if those keywords are typed then do some action accordingly. How is this possible in JavaScript?

a rather simpler yet useful information would help a lot.

Comment: You will need to inject your crawling logic in a content script file and inject into the page. I would suggest please Please read the doumentation.

Comment: can you explain what is a "crawling logic" and read what document?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to implement your keywords logic on content scripts.

If you need necessary information about chrome extensions - it can be found [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview).

At first you can look at extension documentation about [content scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) and [samples](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples).

Documentation for extension API you can find [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/api_index).

Comment: I want to know the logic of how to monitor each webpage and continuously look for keywords, much like how grammarly looks for spelling errors and other grammar errors and highlights them; I want to make an extension that monitors each webpage I visit and looks for keywords that are on there and take action accordingly.

Comment: If you want looks only for keywords in the textfield - than the best way will be just add `change` event listeners on these fields.
If you want to scan all page content and changes on that page - the best way to do it will be with [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver).